# How do i clear this issue? unable to compile?

Tags: linker, cobol, mainframe, jcl

**got this error**

**11.43.36 JOB05184 $HASP165 IBMUSERX ENDED AT N1  MAXCC=12 CN(INTERNAL)**

**IEW2735S DA0F OUTPUT DATA SET FOR DDNAME SYSLMOD HAS INVALID RECORD FORMAT.  R
IEW2008I 0F03 PROCESSING COMPLETED.  RETURN CODE =  12.**

THIS IS MY CODE TO COMPILE:-

```
 //IBMUSERX JOB '285','POLSANI',NOTIFY=&SYSUID,REGION=6M   
 //JOBPROC JCLLIB ORDER=S1304.ANIL.PROC                    
 //COBCL   EXEC  COBCL,MEM=HELLPGM1                        
 //COMPILE.SYSIN DD DSN=IBMUSER.RKSH.COBOL(&MEM),DISP=SHR  
 //LKED.SYSLMOD DD DSN=IBMUSER.RKSH.LOAD(&MEM),DISP=SHR
```

PLEASE SOLVE THIS.

Comment: solve my issue rather than looking at caps

Comment: What are the attributes of the data set `IBMUSER.RKSH.LOAD` ???. The arror points to that being the problem

Comment: IBMUSER is my userid    RKSH IS GROUP AND TYPE IS PDS    IBMUSER.RKSH.LOAD IS DATASETNAME WHERE I WANT TO STORE MY LOAD

Comment: You still have not provided the dataset attributes (LRECL RECFM BLKSIZE) as requested. And turn your caps off and do not post in multiple places at once. I am going to delete any others that I can. Also, this is an error generated by the binder (link editor) and has nothing to do with DB2, cross-compiling, or COBOL so update your tags.

Answer (score 5):

No one here can see what program is really being executed in the LKED step for which you have the SYSLMOD override, but it's probably IEWL (the binder, known in ancient times as the Linkage Editor).

No one here can see what the attributes of your IBMUSER.RKSH.LOAD dataset are, but it must have RECFM=U.

No one here can see which compiler you are using, but from your dataset names it appears you are compiling a COBOL program.  If you are using a COBOL compiler version later than 4.2.1 your IBMUSER.RKSH.LOAD dataset must be a PDSE (**not** a PDS).  If you are using a version of IBM Enterprise COBOL 4.2.1 or earlier, then your IBMUSER.RKSH.LOAD dataset can be either a PDS or a PDSE.  Your compile listing includes which version of the compiler is being invoked.

Your override...

```
//LKED.SYSLMOD DD DSN=IBMUSER.RKSH.LOAD(&MEM),DISP=SHR
```

...should not specify a member name.  It should look like this...

```
//LKED.SYSLMOD DD DSN=IBMUSER.RKSH.LOAD,DISP=SHR
```

Documentation for IBM Enterprise COBOL is available [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos).  Documentation for the binder is available [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=mvs-zos-program-management-users-guide-reference).